# Tracking Down Python / uWSGI Memory Usage

Tags: python, uwsgi

When I run top I see (uWSGI using ~860MB of `RES`; this is in Docker):

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
   11 root      20   0 1048736 360688  19064 S   0.3 17.6   1:17.00 uwsgi
   12 root      20   0 1018840 328140  18964 S   0.3 16.0   1:42.41 uwsgi
```

> RES stands for the resident size, which is an accurate representation of how much actual physical memory a process is consuming.

I would like to understand what is using that much RAM. I tried to use the standard Python heap analysis tools however they don't reveal anything that large. For example using [`pympler`](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html#the-summary-module), I see:

```
                       types |   # objects |   total size
============================ | =========== | ============
                        dict |        7933 |      9.15 MB
                         str |       50742 |      8.40 MB
                        code |       18044 |      2.20 MB
                        type |        2347 |      2.03 MB
                     unicode |        3188 |      1.56 MB
                       tuple |        8012 |    588.46 KB
                        list |        4425 |    550.81 KB
                     weakref |        3707 |    318.57 KB
                         set |         828 |    308.59 KB
  builtin_function_or_method |        3432 |    241.31 KB
                        cell |        3267 |    178.66 KB
         function (__init__) |        1417 |    166.05 KB
           getset_descriptor |        2337 |    164.32 KB
          wrapper_descriptor |        1968 |    153.75 KB
            _sre.SRE_Pattern |         290 |    123.77 KB
```

Could there be some sort of off heap memory usage? Perhaps uwsgi itself is using that much RAM?

*UDPATED*

My current `uwsgi.ini` file:

```
[uwsgi]
strict = true

http = :8000
module = my_service.wsgi
master = true
processes = 2
threads = 2

buffer-size = 10000
```

Comment: Memory lock is an "waste ram resource" ? Created a lot  thread (ETH_PHY, DISK_IO), how to speed up ram I/O without `LOCK` ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @AlexRothberg Can you show the uwsgi config?

Comment: updated with uwsgi.ini

Comment: @AlexRothberg Does so high memory usage exists from the begging of the process or it increases in time? To track the memory usage you can also use http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Options.html#memory-report flag and observe it on uWSGI requests' logs.